# JSON Schema require a specific array element

Tags: json, jsonschema

I defined a list of attributes as json schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
  "type": "object",


  "definitions": {

    "attribute": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "symbolic-name": { "type":"string"},
        "value": { "type":"string"}
      },
      "required": ["symbolic-name", "value"]
    },

    "displayname": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "symbolic-name": {"enum":["displayName"]},
        "value": { "type":"string"}
      },
      "required": ["symbolic-name", "value"]
    }

  },

  "properties": {
    "attributes":{
      "type": "array",
      // This is the crucial point:
      "items": {"oneOf": [
               {"$ref": "#/definitions/attribute"},
               {"$ref": "#/definitions/displayname"}
      ]},
      "uniqueItems": true
    }
  }
}
```

I want to require the list to have exactly one attribute with `symbolic-name="displayName"`

A valid data object would be:

```
{
  "attributes":[
    {"symbolic-name": "displayName", "value": "Display Name"},
    {"symbolic-name": "somethingElse", "value": "value1"}
    {"symbolic-name": "somethingElse", "value": "value2"}
  ]
}
```

Now, this fails to validate as the displayName attribute does not only match "oneOf", but both restrictions. I cannot change it to "allOf", since then all other attributes beside displayName won't match anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for your `"oneOf"` to work, you need your "attribute" and "displayname" schemas to be mutually exclusive- as written, anything that is a valid "displayname" is also a valid "attribute".  We can do that by excluding "displayName" as a valid symbolic name for "attribute":

```
"symbolic-name": {
    "type": "string",
    "not": {"enum": ["displayName"]}
}
```

Now elements with a symbolic name of "displayName" can match the "displayname" definition, but will never match the "attribute" definition.

The other part of your question is about having exactly one "displayname" in your array.  This is trickier.  It also depends on what draft of JSON Schema you are using.  4 and 6 are implemented, and 7 was released on Monday- just declaring `"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#"` means you are using the most recent one, which would be 7.  I recommend using a specific draft for `$schema` instead of the non-numbered one which may change without notice.

If you are OK with requiring the "displayname" to be the *first* element of the array, then this would work in any draft (and you don't even need the `"oneOf"`):

```
"items": [{"$ref": "#/definitions/displayname"}],
"additionalItems": {"$ref": "#/definitions/attribute"}
```

Note that `"items"` is an array here.  This means that the first item MUST be a "displayname" and all additional items beyond that first item MUST be "attribute"s.

If you want to allow the "displayname" at any position, that's harder.  As of draft-06 there is `"contains"`, which requires at least one item to match the given schema.  But there is no easy way to say "at most one item".  However, `"minContains"` and `"maxContains"` have been suggested for draft-08: https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/441

For now, hopefully you are OK with requiring the first position to be the "displayname", as that will work in all drafts.